# How to GET value from URL and add it as hidden field in Contact Form 7

Tags: wordpress, get, contact-form-7, hidden-field, zapier

I'm trying to GET URL parameters and to add it as hidden values into Contact Form 7. The goal is to retrieve them trough a webhook to Zapier.

[I've read this documentation.](https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-the-context/)

I'm trying like this (under the Form tab, at the bottom of my form, just before submit action):

```
[hidden channel default:get]
[hidden campaign default:get]
[hidden campaignid default:get]
[hidden cta default:get]
[hidden language default:get]
[hidden iso default:get]
```

and then it shows up correctly into Zapier plugin tab like this

```
"channel": "??????",
"campaign": "??????",
"campaignid": "??????",
"cta": "??????",
"language": "??????",
"iso": "??????"
```

but after running a test and retrieve the data in Zapier, the field appears without any value in it.

For your information, I've also tried the plugin [Contact Form 7 Get and Show Parameter from URL](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-get-and-show-parameter-from-url/) and it wasn't working iether.

Also, my webhook is perfectly working with my other fields (hidden or form fields). So I know there is no problem from there.

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix to avoid add a new pluggin just for this minor feature
You can add this code in the contact form

```
[hidden URL id:urlField]

<script> //MAYBE ADD THIS BELOW THE SUBMIT BUTTON TO KEEP THE ORDER
if(jQuery("#urlField")) { // JUST TO PREVENT JS ERRORS BUT SHOULD ALLWAYS BE DIFFERENT TO NULL
jQuery("#urlField").val(window.location.href);
}
</script>
```